# How to create column of count of ID in another column in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table "auto_ID" with four columns, "unique_id", "car_id", "car_name," and "car_count".  I want "car_count" to include a count of how many times a given value of "car_id" appears in the column "car_id" as follows.  Please note I am not looking to do a simple groupby, but rather want to add the relevant count to the "car_count" column.  How can I do this in sqlite3?

```
unique_id   car_id   car_name   car_count
1234        1111     Camry      2
2345        2222     Prius      3
3456        1111     Camry      2
4567        2222     Prius      3
5678        3333     Corolla    1
6789        2222     Prius      3
```

I tried using the following commands, but did not get the desired result:

```
UPDATE auto_ID
SET car_count = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT car_id) from auto_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to sqlite didn't support `UPDATE ... FROM`

You can try to write a subquery and `group by car_id` get count then `UPDATE`

**Schema (SQLite v3.18)**

```
CREATE TABLE auto_ID(
   unique_id INT,
   car_id INT,
   car_name VARCHAR(50),
   car_count INT
);


INSERT INTO auto_ID VALUES (1234,1111,'Camry',NULL);
INSERT INTO auto_ID VALUES (2345,2222,'Prius',NULL);
INSERT INTO auto_ID VALUES (3456,1111,'Camry',NULL);
INSERT INTO auto_ID VALUES (4567,2222,'Prius',NULL);
INSERT INTO auto_ID VALUES (5678,3333,'Corolla',NULL);
INSERT INTO auto_ID VALUES (6789,2222,'Prius',NULL);



UPDATE  auto_ID
SET car_count = (
  SELECT t1.cnt FROM(
     SELECT COUNT(*) cnt,t1.car_id id  
     from auto_ID t1
     GROUP BY t1.car_id
  ) t1
  where car_id = t1.id
)
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * from auto_ID;

| unique_id | car_id | car_name | car_count |
| --------- | ------ | -------- | --------- |
| 1234      | 1111   | Camry    | 2         |
| 2345      | 2222   | Prius    | 3         |
| 3456      | 1111   | Camry    | 2         |
| 4567      | 2222   | Prius    | 3         |
| 5678      | 3333   | Corolla  | 1         |
| 6789      | 2222   | Prius    | 3         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9zvTyqhKp6WJYCwmR1RVo6/0)

Answer (score 0):

What does the subquery `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT car_id) from auto_ID` return? For this data it returns 3. Always 3. (Assuming correct syntax, of course).

You need a `WHERE` clause in the subquery. You want to update `car_count` based on the `car_id`. What do you want, for each `car_id`, call it `cid` ? You want `SELECT count(*) from auto_id where car_id = cid`. The subquery needs a `WHERE` clause. Since it is self-referential, you will need an alias of the table name in the subquery.

Something like this will work, but **DON'T LOOK** if you want to figure it out yourself.

> ```
>    UPDATE auto_ID
>    SET car_count = (SELECT COUNT(*)
>    from auto_ID a2
>    where a2.car_id = auto_ID.car_id) ;
> ```